# ModelMapper mapping subclass model to subclass dto

Tags: modelmapper

How can I do this mapping?

**Models:**

```
class Transaction {
  String code;
  Details details;
}
```

```
abstract class Details {}
```

```
class CardDetails extends Details {
  String cardNumber;
}
```

**DTO:**

```
class TransactionDTO {
  String code;
  DetailsDTO details;
}
```

```
abstract class DetailsDTO {}
```

```
class CardDetailsDTO extends DetailsDTO {
  String cardNumber;
}
```

The ModelMapper is mapping `Transaction.code -> TransactionDTO.code` but not `Transaction.details -> TransactionDTO.details` where both details are **CardDetails** and **CardDetailsDTO** respectively